# R: divide rows of specific columns by column of df2 with string-match

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, string-matching

I have a question regarding two dataframes.

I have this kind of data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("a","b","c","d","e"),
                  var1 = c(10,15,12,14,NA))

df2 <- data.frame(Name = c("Nr1","Nr2","Nr100","Nr76"),
                    a_xyz = c(100, 120,130,NA), 
                    b_xyz = c(150,NA,80,90), 
                    c_xyz = c(120,120,NA,140), 
                    d_xyz = c(140,130,150,180), 
                    e_xyz = c(130,120,100,150))
```

I want (maybe a loop) to divide each value of column "a_xyz" from df2 by the value of df1 "a".
I want to do this with every variable in df2, so I have to look for string matches and also if the value exists beforehand. Sadly I don´t have the same names in df1 and df2 ("a" and "a_xyz"), which makes this task more complicated then I wished.

The resulting df3 should look like this in the end:

```
df3 <- data.frame(Name = c("Nr1","Nr2","Nr100","Nr76"),
                  a_xyz = c(10, 12, 13, NA),
                  b_xyz = c(10,NA,5.33,6), 
                  c_xyz = c(10,10,NA,1.667), 
                  d_xyz = c(10,10.83,10.71,12.85), 
                  e_xyz = c(130,120,100,150))
```

Can you guys help me out? Maybe I´m overthinking this and there is a simple solution for this problem.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Lining up by position, `t(t(df2[-1]) / unlist(df1[-1]))` looks right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Some of your final values are not correct so please let me know if there is another definition for computing. Reshape and merge can be done to reach an output similar to the desired one:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
new <- df2 %>% pivot_longer(-Name) %>%
  mutate(val=name) %>%
  separate(val,c('ID','V1'),sep="_") %>%
  left_join(df1) %>%
  mutate(Res=ifelse(!is.na(var1),value/var1,value)) %>%
  select(c(Name,name,Res)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=Res)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  Name  a_xyz b_xyz c_xyz d_xyz e_xyz
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Nr1      10 10     10   10      130
2 Nr2      12 NA     10    9.29   120
3 Nr100    13  5.33  NA   10.7    100
4 Nr76     NA  6     11.7 12.9    150
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
This is a very good solution, but I have one more question. In my real dataset the variables are not always seperated or structured like in df2. Sometimes my variables are called "a_s_xyz" or "a_123_asd". So is there a way to seach specific for a string match of "a"?

Comment: @basti41a Technically the separate option will split your string, after that you could create a condition and store in a new variable the comparison of all separated patterns. In your example, you will have a in the first column always.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to pivot `df1`, which, I think, leads to a reasonably clean solution.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("a","b","c","d","e"),
                  var1 = c(10,15,12,14,NA))

df2 <- data.frame(Name = c("Nr1","Nr2","Nr100","Nr76"),
                  a_xyz = c(100, 120,130,NA), 
                  b_xyz = c(150,NA,80,90), 
                  c_xyz = c(120,120,NA,140), 
                  d_xyz = c(140,130,150,180), 
                  e_xyz = c(130,120,100,150))

df1 <- df1 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = var1)

df3 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(a_xyz = a_xyz / df1$a,
         b_xyz = b_xyz / df1$b,
         c_xyz = c_xyz / df1$c,
         d_xyz = d_xyz / df1$d,
         e_xyz = e_xyz / df1$e)
df3
#>    Name a_xyz     b_xyz    c_xyz     d_xyz e_xyz
#> 1   Nr1    10 10.000000 10.00000 10.000000    NA
#> 2   Nr2    12        NA 10.00000  9.285714    NA
#> 3 Nr100    13  5.333333       NA 10.714286    NA
#> 4  Nr76    NA  6.000000 11.66667 12.857143    NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
This works indeed, but my real dataset is much longer (over 200 variables), so the work done by hand would be very laborious..